# Detect when a failed unlock happens

Tags: java, android, unlock

I've been looking around for a while to find out what happens when a user fails to unlock the phone.

Basically I'm trying to take a picture if a user fails to authenticate. But all I can find is `ACTION_USER_PRESENT` - Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the login attempts of the android lockscreen.

If you want to build an app that does that you have to create your own lockscreen. However, this is not a "real" lockscreen you can't edit in the android settings. This would be an App which acts like a lockscreen and has the same permissions. Because you can check if a phone is locked, that way the app would activate its own "lockscreen" (which is basically a normal form with many permissions) whenever the phone gets locked (you probably have to deactivate the original lockscreen).

Look into [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.html#) link, there you have all options regarding the original lockscreen.